# urlmanager with modules not working in yii2.0

Tags: php, yii2

This regarding module creation inside backend folder.Example i have created a module name as "api". And also sccessfully created controller for that modules.

here is my urlmanager code:

```
  'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => [

                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
                '<module:\w+><controller:\w+>/<action:update|delete>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',

            ],
        ]
```

when i access url with respect to module as "api" , controller as "country" and action as "create"

http://local2host.com/bootstrap/backend/web/index.php/api/country/create
it showing 404 Not Found error

Where i am going wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have registered the module in your backend application's configuration file (usually located in backend/config/main.php)

Answer (score 2):

The second rule will never work, Also you do not have to define the rules and the normal ones will work. So this

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
```

will make this link /website.com/core/contact/index work just fine.

But I am not sure why your route is not catching the first rule... strange. It should.

Comment: Right answer to the question. helped me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Better late then never.

For make module works you need to append it in config:

```
'modules' => [
......
    'modulename' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\modulename\Module',
    ],
......
],
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. He asked about "urlManagement" for Yii2 modules. Your answer shows how to include modules via Yii2 configuration.

Comment: It's a part answer but an important one at that as your module rules won't work unless you specify the above so @Mihai P. answer above is not complete without this.